# text align css for jquery datatable in ie8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, datatable

I would like to align text to center for the first column in jquery datatable.
I have a css, but it doesnt work on ie8.
Besides that, i also use fnAddData.
Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
<table id="table1"> 
<thead>
<th></th><th></th>
<thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>4</td> 
</tr> </tbody> </table>

$('#table1').dataTable({
"sScrollY": "200px",
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"bPaginate": false,
"bJQueryUI": true,
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ -1 ] }
],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false 

});

$('#table1').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    "a","b"],false);

#table1 td:first-child {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
#table1 td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

into

```
#table1 tr:first-child td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

It will select the td's of the first tr of the table

The :first-child selector is supported since IE8. It is part of the CSS 2.1 standard http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Comment: Actually it does, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2 :first-child is supported since IE8. It is part of the CSS 2.1 standard

Comment: i see. thank you. i also want to add css for the second column. is last-child supported? i tried. but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: No last-child is not supported. See http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child What you can do is add a class to each td of your column and style it via its class.